# "TypeError: props.todos.map is not a function" can't figure out what the cause is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to create my first Todo list with React.js. I am trying to change the state from

`const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])`

To:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({
    todo: [],
    isCompleted: false,
  })
```

Just to try and add in a isCompleted state. However, when I change it, I get an error when running my application from a previously working map. The error is in the title.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong?

Code:

**TodosApp.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Todos from "./Todos"

const TodoApp = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState({
    todo: [],
    isCompleted: false,
  })
  const [input, setInput] = useState("")

  const handleCurrentInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(input)
    setInput("")
    setTodos({
      ...todos,
      task: input,
      isCompleted: false,
    })
  }

  const handleDelete = ({ index }) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos]
    newTodos.splice(index, 1)
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }

  return (
    <div id="todoForm">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="todo_form">
          <div class="todo_input">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="input_todo"
                onChange={handleCurrentInput}
                value={input}
              />
            </form>
            <Todos todos={todos} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoApp
```

**Todos.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Todos = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={todo}>
            {todo}
            <button onClick={() => props.handleDelete({ index })}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Todos
```

Comment: When you do `useState({ todo: [], isComplete: false })` You are initializing the todos state as an object.

Comment: okay, so how do I map over it?

Comment: I don't know your use case here. Does `isComplete` a global value for all todos or each todo has an isComplete boolean

Comment: I would go for two separate states instead, one for `todo` one for `isCompleted`. I think you're making it more difficult than it needs to be by putting all the data in a single object.

Comment: But how would I keep both the todo and iscompleted merged? Basically for eg, if there was 3 todos, it would be like

todo: 'second todo'
isCompleted: true


todo: 'third todo'
isCompleted: false

todo: 'first todo'
isCompleted: false 

and if it is completed, mark it with a line or something

Comment: @BasvanderLinden it's depend on his use case.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to create a `Todo` component that knows of itself whether it is completed or not, and to render multiple of these `Todo` components using a map for example.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Yes but that is not the question actually

Comment: @HichamELBSI I understand, but sometimes it's better to take a different approach than to actually solve a certain problem. But the accepted answer is of course a good way to do it too.

Comment: @DonnieBerry : I have also answered your question. Few points that I would like to add here. 1) Every task should have a unique id indexes don't serve the purpose. I have should a quick trick to create unique ids in my code. 2) deleteHandler is improved by me also in my code... We can directly use ES6 filter method to do the task and this saves a lot of code. Remember filter() is non-mutable also :) Hope these points will also help :) I have provided a working solution also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to focus on each `todo` item including 2 props `task, isCompleted` instead of `isCompleted` of `todos`.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
var newTodo = {
                task: 'React JS',
                isCompleted: false
             };
setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
```

Then your `todos`'s structure like below:

```
[
    {
        task: 'Study React JS',
        isCompleted: false
    },
    {
        task: 'Study React Redux',
        isCompleted: false
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your state is an object containing an array of todos. This is what you're passing to your `Todos` component.

So you have two options:

1. Either pass `todos.todos` as a prop or
2. (Better way) Rethink your state. `isCompleted` seems that it should be part of each todo, because each todo should be completed not the list itself. A list is completed if every todo `isCompleted`
   So your state would be `const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])`

I hope it's clear what I mean. Typing this from the phone is not so easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't set to state the right way, `todos` got overwritten with the wrong value. You should write:

```js
    // handleSubmit
    setTodos(s => {
      ...s,
      task: input,
      isCompleted: false,
    });
```

and

```js
    // handleDelete
    const newTodos = [...todos]
    newTodos.splice(index, 1)
    setTodos(s => ({ ...s, todos: newTodos }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working App: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hdoxhl)

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TodoApp = () => {
  /* initialize todos with array 
  instead of an object               */
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleCurrentInput = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input);
    /* update the state by appending an object having 
       key todo and isCompleted to copy of our main state, 
       todos.
     */
    setTodos([...todos, { todo: input, isCompleted: false }]);
    setInput("");
  };

  const handleDelete = ({ index }) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(index, 1);
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);

  return (
    <div id="todoForm">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="todo_form">
          <div class="todo_input">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="input_todo"
                onChange={handleCurrentInput}
                value={input}
              />
            </form>
            <Todos todos={todos} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoApp;

const Todos = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {props.todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {/**use null propogation to avoid accessing the null todo value which will not exist in first render. */}
              {todo?.todo}
              <button onClick={() => props.handleDelete({ index })}>
                Delete
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`isCompleted` should be associated with each todo item.
So, you should use `todos` as array and store objects within that array. Each object  will have `isCompleted` and a `task` property along with a unique `Id` as well.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

And your submit input would look like:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = {
      task: input,
      id: new Date().getTime().toString(), 
      isCompleted: false
    };
    const updatedTodos = [...todos, todo];

    setTodos(updatedTodos);

    console.log(updatedTodos);
    setInput("");
  };
```

**Note:** To generate unique Ids you can use `uuid` library. I have generated unique ids here using `id: new Date().getTime().toString()`.

**FULL WORKING CODE SANDBOX LINK:**  https://codesandbox.io/s/todosissue-2mc26?file=/src/TodoApp.js

Have modified `handleDelete` function as well :)